# pyspark sql convert date format from mm/dd/yy hh:mm or yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss into yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm format

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 date format(`MM/dd/yy HH:mm` and `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`) in start time that needs to convert into `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm` format. How do I handle both data format in single below select statement to convert into desired format

```
df1 = spark.sql("""select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(strt_tm,'MM/dd/yy HH:mm'),'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm) as starttime from table1""")
```

Input

```text
strt_tm          
12/11/21 01:15
2021-12-11 11:15:12
```

output:

```text
strt_tm 
2021-12-11 01:15
2021-12-11 11:15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `coalesce` to handle both formats along with [`to_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#to_timestamp) or [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#to_date) functions:

```py
spark.createDataFrame(
    [("12/11/21 01:15",), ("2021-12-11 11:15:12",)], ["strt_tm"]
).createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

spark.sql("""
select coalesce(
            to_timestamp(strt_tm, 'dd/MM/y HH:mm'), 
            to_timestamp(strt_tm, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
        ) as start_time,
        coalesce(
            to_date(strt_tm, 'dd/MM/y HH:mm'), 
            to_date(strt_tm, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
        ) as start_date
from table1
""").show()

#+-------------------+----------+
#|         start_time|start_date|
#+-------------------+----------+
#|2021-11-12 01:15:00|2021-11-12|
#|2021-12-11 11:15:12|2021-12-11|
#+-------------------+----------+
```